# What type of material should be used for sole plates on screened in porch?

Tags: screens

I'm following along in a guide to installing a screened in porch and the following photo is shown.

[image: sole plate]

The instructions are 'Secure sole plates to the patio or porch floor using construction adhesive and appropriate mechanical fasteners'

What kind of material is this? Is it just a composite 2x4?

I've heard of ScreenTight screening kits, but they aren't available nearby... are there any other screening kits that you would suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be composite material.  Pressure treated 2x4 would work.  An adhesive with the appropriate fasteners will anchor it well.

Don't know of other kits besides screentight.  I would check your local home stores and online.  You can roll your own but the end result may not be as taut as you'd like.

Good luck.